# Path is not working

Tags: iphone

```
NSBundle *thisBundleb = [NSBundle mainBundle];

pathb = [thisBundleb pathForResource:[a3 objectAtIndex:0] ofType:@"html"];

NSURL   *instructionsURLb = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:pathb];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:instructionsURLb]];
```

value of [a3 objectAtIndex:0]=index but when i pass like this i am getting
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'**

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pathForResource:ofType: is returning nil, and initFileURLWithPath: is complaining about it.  Trap that error like so:

```
if(nil == pathb) {
    NSLog("Couldn't find object named %@", [a3 objectAtIndex:0]);
} else {
    NSURL   *instructionsURLb = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:pathb];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:instructionsURLb]];          
}
```

and double check that you're searching for an object that actually exists in your bundle.

Comment: it is existing if i type  @"index"  then its working fine . else not :(
i tried your code and i got this
-[UIRoundedRectButton length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b14ab0
2010-08-09 08:40:37.924 ramdev[1641:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIRoundedRectButton length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b14ab0'

Comment: Then whatever is returned by `[a3 objectAtIndex:0]` is not what you're expecting it to be. Verify that the `a3` array is valid and that it actually contains the string `@"index"` at index 0.

Comment: Doesn't sound like [a3 objectAtIndex:0] == @"index", then.

Comment: hey [a3 objectAtIndex:0] == index   not @"index"  should i make it like @"index"?? ohh god let me try then

Comment: i think path for rsource looks for this path
file://localhost/Users/applefan/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/3.1.3/Applications/A582538C-75CF-48BB-B864-74CCA1BA6900/ramdev.app/  so i think i have to append this along with index then only it will become complete ???

Comment: hey i did even this NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@\"%@\"",[a3 objectAtIndex:0]];  == @"index" still no luck ???

Comment: I think the string you're constructing there is actually @"@"index"", not @"index".  When we write @"index", only the text between the quotes is the string itself.  The @ tells us that it's an NSString*, not a C-style null-terminated char array.

Comment: Also, pathForResource should be giving you the path you're describing.

Comment: ok see value of my string is  s==@"index"   (for sure)
pathb = [thisBundleb pathForResource:s ofType:@"html"];
now when i pass like this NSURL *instructionsURLb = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
  
  NSLog(@"[ath  1 IS  %@",instructionsURLb );==NULL??

Comment: i will update in new thread i guess .. its messy here  
Thanks Seamus i will make it more clear in new thread

Comment: My suggestion here is that you take this one step at a time.  Rather than checking the value of instructionsURLb, see if you're getting a sane value for pathb.  Only when you have something that looks like good output from pathForResource:ofType should you worry about opening it.

Comment: YOu are right my path =null  but pathForResource:s is having @"index" value  oh god what i am doing wrong daaam ok i will cross check again

Comment: wow yes i did it thanks a lot i have to do UTF8encoding before path :-) thanks a lot SEAMUS

Answer (score 1):

Is your `index.html` actually named `Index.html`? I believe `pathForResource:ofType` is case sensitive.

Comment: Seems like it is case sensitive only on the device (ipad) and not in the simulator.